# Constructor and Overloaded Operator Execution Order

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm little confused about my this code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
    public:
        A(){
            cout << "Constructor" << endl;
        }
        ~A(){
            cout << "Destructor" << endl;
        }
        void operator ~(){
            cout << "\nOverloaded Operator";

        }
};
int main(){
    ~A();
    cout << "\nBefore End";
}
```

**Output**

```
Constructor

Overloaded OperatorDestructor

Before End
```

I want to ask that on `~A();`  line of code constructor `A();` creates the object, then that object is calling the operator? If not then please explain how it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A()` creates a temporary of type `A`, that you invoke `operator~()` on, and which gets destroyed at the end of the line.

The destructor is a special member function - but it's still a member function. As such, if you're going to invoke it directly - which should be done in only rare, special cases - it still has to be invoked on an object. For instance, this example will invoke the destructor:

```
A().~A();
```

However, it will destroy that `A` temporary twice, which is bad.

Comment: with your first paragraph A when will destroy? end of which line? end of this line? `cout << "\nOverloaded Operator";` or the end of operator body?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq The end of the `~A();` line

Comment: will this destroy the object ? `A().~A();` then why it should be twice as you said in last line.

Comment: @AsifMushtaq Because the implicit destructor call will happen regardless of whether you called it explicitly or not.

Comment: sorry to bother you, then why we say Destructor called when objects goes out of scope? `A().~A();` delete the object already there no object now, then why implicit destructor called?

Answer (score 3):

That it would be more visible enclose the call of ~A() in braces

```
int main(){
    {   
            ~A();
    }
    cout << "\nBefore End";
}
```

So at first there will be created a temporary object calling the default constructor. Then there will be called member function `operator ~` and after finishing the statement there will be called the destructor.

This call

```
~A();
```

is equivalent to

```
A().operator ~();
```

If you would write for example the following way

```
A().A::~A();
```

or

```
A().~A();
```

then in this case there would be called the destructor and the program would have undefined behaviour because the destructor woulb be called two times.